# How to set Here map language to English on MapViewLite View? It automatically changes to Hindi in India

Tags: android, here-api

Im developing an app which uses Here Map Lite Android SDK. When i zoom in to Chennai(India) to automatically changes language to Hindi. How to Change it to English

```
private fun loadMapScene() {
        if (checkPermission())
            mapView.mapScene.loadScene(MapStyle.NORMAL_DAY) {
                if (it == null) {
                    mapView.camera.target = GeoCoordinates(52.530932, 13.384915)
                    mapView.camera.zoomLevel = 14.0
                } else {
                    Log.d(_errTAG, "loadMapScene failed: $it")
                }
            }
        else requestPermission()
    }
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9KZk.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This starts working with version 4.1.6

```
private void loadMapScene() {
      MapSceneConfig mapSceneConfig = new MapSceneConfig();
      mapSceneConfig.mainLanguageCode = LanguageCode.EN_EN;
      mapSceneConfig.fallbackLanguageCode = LanguageCode.EN_EN;

mapView.getMapScene().loadScene(MapStyle.NORMAL_DAY, mapSceneConfig, new MapScene.LoadSceneCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadScene(@Nullable MapScene.ErrorCode errorCode) {
        if (errorCode == null) {
            mapView.camera.target = GeoCoordinates(52.530932, 13.384915);
                mapView.camera.zoomLevel = 14.0;
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "onLoadScene failed: " + errorCode.toString());
        }
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the language using the language code inherited from the class 
`java.lang.Enum<LanguageCode>`. Check more here

> https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk/api_reference/com/here/sdk/core/LanguageCode.html#AS_IN